# Is it possible to remove a task in docker (docker swarm)?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Suppose I had 3 replicated images:

`docker service create --name redis-replica --replicas=3 redis:3.0.6`

Consider that there are two nodes connected (including the manager), and running the command `docker service ps redis-replica` yields this:

```
ID                  NAME                  IMAGE               NODE                DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE            ERROR               PORTS
x1uumhz9or71        redis-replica.1       redis:3.0.6         worker-vm            Running             Running 9 minutes ago                        
j4xk9inr2mms        redis-replica.2       redis:3.0.6         manager-vm       Running             Running 8 minutes ago                                    
ud4dxbxzjsx4        redis-replica.3       redis:3.0.6         worker-vm       Running             Running 9 minutes ago
```

As you can see all tasks are running.

I have a scenario I want to fix:

Suppose I want to remove a `redis` container on the `worker-vm`. Currently there are two, but I want to make it one.

I could do this by going into the `worker-vm`, removing the container by `docker rm`. This poses a problem however:

Once docker swarm sees that one of the tasks has gone down, it will immediately spit out another `redis` image on another node (manager or worker). As a result I will always have 3 tasks.

This is not what I want. Suppose I want to force docker to not relight another image if it is removed.

Is this currently possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Swarm mode, it is the orchestrator who's scheduling the tasks for you. Task is the unit of scheduling and each task invokes exactly one container.

What this means in practice is, that you are not supposed to manage tasks manually. Swarm takes care of this for you.

You need to describe the desired state of your service, if you have placement preferences you can use the `--placement-pref`, in `docker service` commands. You can specify number of replicas, etc. E.g.

```
docker service create \
  --replicas 9 \
  --name redis_2 \
  --placement-pref 'spread=node.labels.datacenter' \
  redis:3.0.6
```

You can limit the set of nodes where the task will be placed using placement constraints (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints---constraint. Here is an example from the Docker docs:

```
$ docker service create \
  --name redis_2 \
  --constraint 'node.labels.type == queue' \
  redis:3.0.6
```

I think that's the closest solution to control tasks.

Once you described your placement constraints/preferences, Swarm will make sure that the actual state of your service is in line with the desired state that you described in the create command. You are not supposed to manage any further details after describing the desired state.

If you change the actual state by killing a container for example, Swarm will re-align the state of your service to be in-line with your desired state again. This is what happened when you removed your container.

In order to change the desired state you can use the `docker service update` command.

The key point is that tasks are not equal to containers. Technically they invoke exactly one container, but they are not equal. Task is like a scheduling slot where the scheduler places a container.

The Swarm scheduler manages tasks (not you), that's why there is no command like `docker task`. You drive the mechanism by describing the desired state.

**To answer your original question, yes it is possible to remove a task, you can do it by updating the desired state of your service.**

Comment: Hey @Mark, thanks for the reply. I see that for the `docker service update` commands, there is one that could be helpful for me, particularly the one `--replicas uint`. After I create lets say 3 tasks, I can perform `docker service update redis_2 --replicas 2`, then docker will remove a single task from any of the 3, making it 2. This is good, but I would like to have the flexibility to **choose** which task I want to remove. Is there an option for this? The `--replicas` only allows me to specify the new amount of replicas we want, not which task to get rid of

Comment: You can scale a service with `docker service scale SERVICE=REPLICAS`. Regrading which task to remove, I think what you are trying to achieve is not feasible directly. Look into placement constraints of services, that's where you can get more control. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/service_create/#specify-service-constraints---constraint

Comment: hi @takacsmark , it is reasonable to have the swarm managing the service tasks, however I have a traefik task in a "New 3 weeks ago" state (without any container associated, it never started), it also has an old traefik version, I already updated the service image but the old one is still here, and I can not stop the service because it is productive, in this case I would like to manage this task to be sure that it will never start, any suggestion?